# ydn-DB doesn't work with iOS8 Safari

Tags: safari, ios8, ydn-db

I recently updated my ipad to iOS8 and the HTML/Javascript app stopped working because safari on iOS8 cannot recognize ydn-db object.

Has anybody else also facing this issue? Any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen [this issue](https://github.com/yathit/ydn-db/issues/20)? Safari 7.1 (also Safari 8) has [a bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136937) (currently unconfirmed) that could not create transaction with multiple Object Stores.

As a workaround, use WebSQL instead, as follow:

```
var db = new ydn.db.Storage('db name', schema, {mechanisms: ['websql', 'indexeddb']);
```

Comment: This also worked for me - the problem started when adding the icon to the home screen... - as described in [this Apple support article](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6549513)